# Elasticsearch validate query API fails for query with highlight

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to use `highlight` with my query as mentioned here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/highlighting.html.

This query works correctly with `search` API but before actually executing the expensive query, I want to validate it using `validation` API provided by elasticsearch: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-validate.html

But this fails with an error message:

```
org.elasticsearch.common.ParsingException: request does not support [highlight]
```

So how can I validate the query with highlight without executing it?

I found a similar problem on ES discussion forum: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/validation-api-got-error-with-highlight-org-elasticsearch-common-parsingexception-request-does-not-support-highlight/248953 but it doesn't have any solution.

Comment: What you wan to validate ? because seach-explain api is not for validation but it is for how your specific document is matching with query and how score is calculated for specific document. May be you ahve putted wrong url in question.

Comment: @SagarPatel, thanks, I added incorrect link in the question. Updated it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not support highlighting (or any other param like sort, aggregation, size, from etc.) because the purpose of the validation API is to validate your query, and highlighting is done after the query is executed and get a response from the index.

> Validates a potentially expensive query without executing it.

Hence, you can remove the highlighting when running the validation API and validating the query. after that you can add highlghtng in actual query.

Comment: But in my application, user generates query and highlight. So what if highlight field is faulty? Is there a way to validate it separately? I couldn't find it.

Comment: You can validate at application end. because this validate api for just validating query and not other params like sort, highlighting, etc..

Comment: Hmm, one option is to validate the query using `validation` API by removing the highlight field and then separately use `search` API without any query or the most inexpensive query with this highlight field. In this manner we can validate both optimally and also remove responsibility of validating highlight at out end (in application). What do you think?

Comment: Yes correct, but why are you giving user option to generate highlight as well. You can just give option to create query and highlighting you can keep internal. Or, you can give option to user to select on which field they want highlghting and based on that you can build highlighting query in application.

Comment: Yeah that makes more sense but that's something out of my control in the application. Anyways thanks for the hint, that helped me figure out the solution.

Comment: its glad that it helps you.